# Force redrawing when scrolling the data grid views?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WinForms form, I have a Table Layout Panel and two DataGridViews (`DGV1` and `DGV2`). Lines are drawn between the two data grid views.

```
private void TableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawLines(e.Graphics);
}

private void DrawLines(Graphics g)
{
    var DGV1Rows = GetVisibleDataGridViewRows(DGV1);
    var DGV2Rows = GetVisibleDataGridViewRows(DGV2);
    var lines = GetLines(DGV1Rows, DGV2Rows); // Find all relations between two grid views
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        g.DrawLine(line.Pen, line.R1, line.C1, line.R2, line.C2);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<(int R1, int C1, int R2, int C2, Pen Pen)> GetLines(
    IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> Rows1,
    IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> Rows2)
{ .... // return the lines between the rows of the two grids. 
       // the line will point to the bottom of the grids if the rows are not visible in another side
}

IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> GetVisibleRows(DataGridView dgv)
{
    var visibleRowsCount = dgv.DisplayedRowCount(true);
    var firstVisibleRowIndex = dgv.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
    for (int i = firstVisibleRowIndex; i < firstVisibleRowIndex + visibleRowsCount; i++)
    {
        yield return dgv.Rows[i];
    }
}
```

The lines were drawn after the application run. However, the lines are not redrawn if scrolling the rows in the grids? How to force it to redraw the lines when scrolling?

Comment: The DataGridView has a scroll event.  Maybe try calling `TableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();` from there.

Comment: I found your approach is better than calling `DrawLines(TableLayoutPanel1.CreateGraphics())` in the `Paint` event of the data grid view, which may not refresh the lines.

Comment: Your posted code didn't have a CreateGraphics call in it.  If I would have seen that, I would have scolded you for it.  :-)

Comment: So `CreateGraph()` is bad and should be avoided?

Comment: `CreateGraphics()` is rarely ever the right approach...